# How can I define an instance for a specific type application in Haskell 98?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I noticed that the test suite for `Data.Set` only really defines `Arbitrary Set a` sensibly for `a ~ Int`, but to avoid the GHC special `~` it uses

```
instance Enum a => Arbitrary (Set a)
```

How can I make sure only the `Arbitrary (Set Int)` instance is used without needing any GHC extensions? In GHC-only code, I'd use either `FlexibleInstances` or `GADTs` and then either

```
instance Arbitrary (Set Int)
```

or

```
instance a ~ Int => Arbitrary (Set a)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is possible using an idea I think I first encountered in a paper by Oleg Kiselyov, and which underlies `Control.Lens.Equality`.

```
import Data.Functor.Identity

class IsInt a where
  fromIntF :: f Int -> f a

instance IsInt Int where
  fromIntF fx = fx

toIntF :: IsInt a => g a -> g Int
toIntF = unf . fromIntF . F $ id

newtype F g a b = F {unf :: g b -> a}

fromInt :: IsInt a => Int -> a
fromInt = runIdentity . fromIntF . Identity

toInt :: IsInt a => a -> Int
toInt = runIdentity . toIntF . Identity
```

Now I can use

```
instance IsInt a => Arbitrary (Set a)
```

and be confident that I'm really dealing with `Int`. For convenience, I can constrain the `IsInt` class with any classes I need of which `Int` is an instance:

```
class (Show a, Read a, Integral a, Arbitrary a) => IsInt a where ...
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning: this gives you the guarantee you want outside the system, but not inside it. That is, GHC won't infer from `IsInt a` that `a ~ Int`. This can occasionally require annoying additional type annotations. I don't think that can be helped purely within H98 (or H2010), though.

Comment: @DanielWagner, yes, it is definitely inferior to GHC's approach. If equality constraints are ever standardized, I will definitely prefer them. But `containers` generally tries to be as "portable" as possible, so if I can do what I need without an extension, I will.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I think it's also worth noting that this implementation is compatible with GHC's, in that you can apply `fromIntF` to `Refl :: Int :~: Int` to get something of type `IsInt a => Int :~: a`. Indeed, this will work for any similar equality type, regardless of how it fits into the language.